# How to setup .net core rewriting with angular in a multilingual setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, url-rewriting, .net-core

I have a multilingual Angular 5 app hosted in an .NET core MVC site hosted under IIS. The structure is as follows:

- site/ (English site)
- site/fr (French site)

We have the following rewrite config

```html
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Refresh page" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="(.+)\.(css|jpg|gif|png|ico|js|json|woff2|map|otf|woff|ttf)$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/login" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/logout" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/signin" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/signout" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/api/authentication/token" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="?path={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Then in our home controller:

```
 if (!Request.Path.Value.Contains("/fr/") && primaryLanguage.IndexOf("fr", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
      //HttpContext.Request.PathBase = "/fr";
      var uri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(Request.Scheme, Request.Host, new PathString("/fr/"), Request.Path, Request.QueryString);
      return Redirect(uri);
    }
```

Unfortunately, after the site gets redirected to site/fr the url gets rewritten to site/?path=fr and we enter a recursive loop.

How do we have a multilingual site that supports the angular html5 routing hosted in the MVC site?